# T-SQL : how to get smallest and largest number that can be created using x digits

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can we create a function or a procedure that will return the smallest and largest number that can be created by x digits like eg: 6 digits

```
Smallest : 100000
Largest  : 999999
```

Comment: Wouldn't the smallest be `000001`?

Comment: Either way, to answer your question: Yes, we (I) can.

Comment: I think not because its suppose to be 1 digit number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use `REPLICATE`. I don't explicitly `CAST`/`CONVERT` the value to a numerical data type here, but you can add the functionality trivially if you need to:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.YourFunction (@digits tinyint) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    SELECT '1' + REPLICATE('0',@Digits - 1) AS Smallest,
           REPLICATE('9',@digits) AS Largest;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourFunction(7);
GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.YourFunction;
```